# Retrieving map value using key in Scala Play Framework view

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

I've passed a map of `[String, List[String]]` to one of my views in Play. The user is selecting a value from a dropdown. This value is a key in my map. I am using this key to then populate a second dropdown using the value in the map - a list of `String`. However, I do not know how to use Play's template language to get the value out of my map since I'm retrieving the key via JavaScript.

This is my code:

```
function selectSubCat() {
        var key = $("#monthYear").find(":selected").text(); // get the selected option's text. This is the map key.

// Here lies the issue. mailingRunDates is the name of the map I've passed to the view. Play says: val key not found.
        var runDatesList = @mailingRunDates(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to communicate javascript with the playframework template engine. And I am afraid you can't do it except if [you are trying to communicate with a controller using ajax](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.2/ScalaJavascriptRouting#Javascript-Routing).

In your case the compiler is looking for a variable declared as a [dynamic statement](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates#Syntax:-the-magic-%E2%80%98@%E2%80%99-character). It is code that is run in the server, so when the template is transformed into html it cannot be changed. You can declare a variable in the template system using something like `@{key=12}`.

So in this case, I would extract all the `Map[String, List[String]]` to a javascript object to create that functionality in javascript.